# Authenticate user from iOS Rails 3 server and Omniauth

Tags: ios, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

Our Rails 3 app uses facebook-omniauth, allowing users to authenticate with facebook.

It'd be nice to use as much of the web based authentication system as possible, so I tried following the answer (the one that hasn't been down-voted) to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376878/how-to-authenticate-users-from-an-ios-app-against-a-rails-3-application-using-om) but I can't get it to work.

The gist of the answer is:

> omniauth-facebook will handle requests to the callback endpoint with an access_token parameter without any trouble. Easy :)

So to test this, in my browser I'm issuing the following request:

```
/users/auth/facebook_api/callback?access_token=BAAB...
```

But in my server log, I see:

```
(facebook) Callback phase initiated.
(facebook) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, : 
{"error":{"message":"Missing authorization code","type":"OAuthException","code":1}}
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Is the fact that I'm trying to do this through the browser to test messing something up? Any other ideas on how I can reuse my www based auth logic for my ios app?

**UPDATE:**
I'm not sure, but I'm following [this guide](http://www.wealsodocookies.com/posts/how-to-create-multiple-facebook-omniauth-strategies-for-the-same-application) in order to have multiple facebook omniauth strategies, one for www and another for mobile.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this? I'm having exactly the same problem! This is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341867/how-to-authenticate-with-facebook-using-rest-with-devise-omniauth

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't, but I just posted my workaround as an official answer. I don't know how the poster in the question I linked to got his solution to work, but I absolutely couldn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I never found a solution in line with what I was asking originally, but here is how I solved it: Take the access token you get on the iPhone and send it up to your server and perform the login manually.

```
def facebook_login
  graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(params[:user][:fb_access_token])
  profile = graph.get_object('me')
  omniauth = build_omniauth_hash(profile)

  @user = User.find_or_create_for_facebook_oauth(omniauth)
end
```

On www we already had a method called `find_or_create_for_facebook_oauth`, and that took the result from Omniauth and either found the user or created a new one. In order to utilize that method for mobile, I had to build up a similar structure by hand so I could pass it as an argument.

```
def build_omniauth_hash(profile)
  struct = OpenStruct.new
  struct.uid = profile['id']
  struct.info = OpenStruct.new
  struct.info.email = profile['email']
  struct.info.image = "http://graph.facebook.com/#{profile['id']}/picture?type=square"
  struct.info.first_name = profile['first_name']
  struct.info.last_name = profile['last_name']
  struct.info.bio = profile['bio']
  struct.info.hometown = profile['hometown']['name'] if profile['hometown']
  struct.info.location = profile['location']['name'] if profile['location']
  struct
end
```

Comment: thanks man, I'll do this and if I found something else I'll update you here!